How can I remove all installed libraries from a databricks cluster via the CLI?
How can I use the databricks-CLI to remove all existing whl files from a databricks cluster?
In the UI I would remove all entries under "libraries" in the cluster configuration and restart the cluster.
I tried to figure it out how it works with the CLI, I can see a databricks clusters edit -h command, but cannot find a subcommand to clear any installed libraries.

I ended up using a pipeline step to redeploy the cluster via Terraform and re-setting the library option to clear it. Don't like this "solution" very much though.
If you know a better solution, please add your answer.
